# Как получить строку md5 в Golang

Tags: golang, md5

делаю так

```
pass := []byte(user.Password)
hash := md5.New()
hash.Write(pass)
md5string := string(hash.Sum(nil))
fmt.Println(md5string)
```

и на выходе получаю что то вроде `��N�w|�♂��,a;�¶�`

хотя если сделать например `fmt.Printf("%x", md5string)` то нормально все. Как мне все таки получить строку md5?

Comment: Вы хотите получить результат в виде строки, верно?

Comment: конечно в виде строки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hash.Sum` выдаст вам просто байты. Чтобы сериализовать, выберите формат сериализации и используйте его. Например, [`encoding/hex`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/):

```
md5string := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
```

Кстати, для паролей сейчас не рекомендуется использовать MD5. Для большей надёжности рекомендуют [BCrypt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt).